# Visual Studio vs Source Tree. Pulling in a clear state and found uncommited changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there any kind of problem between Visual Studio (v2008) and Source Tree?.

I commit some changes in a branch. Change to develop branch... Then do a pull. Pull is clean but when i enter Source Tree , it updates telling me i have uncommitted changes.. that i had not before!.

Checking them, it does things from a long time ago. I cannot compile... Where does it come from??.

I also found out that when you have a conflict, it saves the ORIG file and it does not delete it. Its annoying...

Answer (score 1):

I found out an answer for this mistery:

Apparently, if you have Visual Studio opened (in some cases) and you open SourceTree. If you checkout other branch or develop branch and you were in another branch, Visual Studio does not understand files changed underneath and keeps track of old ones somehow.

That's why SourceTree finds you have some changes and files that are different all the time. No matter how many times you do "stash" to those changes, they will appear all the time.

So the way to fix this is to **CLOSE visual studio** and saying yes to update all files that have changed. Source Tree will no longer tell you you have uncommitted changes anymore.